# Rails with pjax, pjax:complete event is raised, but full page loads regardless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pjax

I am trying to use pjax with my Rails app.I  am not using a gemified version of pjax (i.e. I downloaded the plain JS version). I get the alert messages but the entire page still reloads.

My layout page looks like this:

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title Cassandra
        = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
        = javascript_include_tag 'application'
        = csrf_meta_tags

    body
        = render('layouts/navbar')

        div#content.row
            div#pjax-container.large-12.columns
                = render('layouts/breadcrumbs')
                = render('layouts/flash')
                = yield

        = render('layouts/footer')
```

My js looks like this (inside a doc.ready)

```
    $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container');

    $(document).on('pjax:send', function() {
        alert('pjax start');
    })
    $(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
       alert('pjax comp');
    })
```

I get no console errors in Chrome and I will know for sure when it works because right now I 
have not modified any server responses to not include the layout page, and the layout page will need to be tweaked etc, but right now I just want to get the scaffolding working

Comment: No, do I have to for it to work, I thought it can return the layout and all and inject it into the pjax container for now (obviously it will look like a mess with nested menus etc), and when that works then I will check headers and return the view without its layout?

Comment: @kingdamian42 you might want to put that as the answer, pjax ovbiously checks and rejects content that contains <head/html> elements

Comment: No I just misunderstood your question. You can load the entire page like that even with head/html elements. So that's not the answer. That's why I deleted my comment.

Comment: The thing is what you suggested works...I looked here and I cannot see any rejection of full pages https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js, but when I do a server side check for  pjx and skip the layout, I can look at the Chrome Network view and check the pjax requests instead of the full reload

Comment: Although I did a 10 second cntrl-f 'head/html' check